# How can I send a Signal from ESP32 to Raspberry pi using Cables

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I want the ESP32 to give a Signal to the Raspberry when the ESP detects an object with an ultrasonic Sensor. After receiving the Signal, the Raspberry makes a photo.

My problem is that I tried to use the Signal code from a LED "signal" but it won't work. It always shows, when the Raspberry and the ESP have connected this issue in the mirror :

```
mmal: mmal_vc_port_enable: failed to enable port vc.null_sink:in:0(OPQV): ENOSPC
mmal: mmal_port_enable: failed to enable connected port (vc.null_sink:in:0(OPQV))0x1d08dc0 (ENOSPC)
mmal: mmal_connection_enable: output port couldn't be enabled
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "camera.py", line 18, in <module>
    cam = PiCamera()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 433, in __init__
    self._init_preview()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 513, in _init_preview
    self, self._camera.outputs[self.CAMERA_PREVIEW_PORT])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/renderers.py", line 558, in __init__
    self.renderer.inputs[0].connect(source).enable()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 2212, in enable
    prefix="Failed to enable connection")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 184, in mmal_check
    raise PiCameraMMALError(status, prefix)
picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to enable connection: Out of resources


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)
Press return to continue
```

I already tried fixing id using the `app.run(host = '0.0.0.0')` but it shows me the same issue.

Here is my Python Code :

```py
import time
import os                                                                                       # import the time
from picamera import PiCamera                                                                   # import image from the camera into the Raspberry
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)                                                                          # define pins

GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.IN)                                                                         # setup pin 11 as input


if __name__=='__main__':
    while True:
        if(GPIO.input(11) == GPIO.HIGH):



            #Variables
            cam = PiCamera()
                                                                                                # make the variable cam 

            #Define how newimagen is made of (Variable)                                         # make the variable fname which give us the date and Time 
            os.chdir('/home/pi/Desktop/image/')                                                 # Define where we are working now 
            images = [i for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if i.lower().startswith('image')]      # define what images is : 
                                                                                                # os.listdir returns a list containing of the entries in the directory os.getcwd...
                                                                                                # os.getcwd returns the current working directory of a process --> '/home/pi/Desktop/'

            if images:
                newest = max(images, key=os.path.getmtime)                                      # max() is a method that returns the largest item of sth
                                                                                                # os.path.getmtime return the time of last modification
            else:
                newest = 'image0.jpg'


            number = int(''.join([i for i in newest if i.isdigit()]))                           #number is the number of the newest image : image1 --> number = 1. This method look up if there is an image and which number it has
            newimagen = 'image'+str(number+1)+'.jpg'                                            # newimagen is the variable that decide which image it will be(image1 or image2...)

            #Camera Code changing 
            cam.resolution = (2592,1944)                                                        # method to change the resoltuion

            #Main Code      
            cam.capture('/home/pi/Desktop/image/'+newimagen)
```

Here is my Arduino Code:

```
// defines pins numbers

#define trigPin 12
#define echoPin 13
#define ledPin  14

// defines variables
long duration;
int distance;

boolean triggered = false;

double activateDistance = 10;

void setup() {
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600); // Starts the serial communication

}

void loop() 
{
  // Clears the trigPin
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);

  // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
delayMicroseconds(5);
digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);
digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);



  // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);

  // Calculating the distance
  distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;

  // Prints the distance on the Serial Monitor
  if (distance <= activateDistance)
  {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    Serial.print("GOT");
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);
  }else{
    digitalWrite(ledPin,LOW);
  }

}
```

Currently it only makes a LED turn on and I thought (so does a friend) that it is possible to use the same code for sending a Signal to the Raspberry.

It would be very great if the people in this community could help me. If there is any problem, don't hesitate to correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to minimize the problem cause.

From the error I see, the problem is that the `PiCamera` module couldn't work properly, so I think it is better to test your pi and see if it works properly with this test code source from [here](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/quickstart.html):

```
import time
import picamera

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.start_preview()
    time.sleep(10)
    camera.stop_preview()
```

If it doesn't work then you can focus only on the real problem.

Also, i suspect that the presence of `cam = PiCamera()` inside while loop might be the problem, please move it before the loop and check again i.e.:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
# make the variable cam
    cam = PiCamera()

    while True:
        if(GPIO.input(11) == GPIO.HIGH):
        # and the rest of your code
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for answering. First I tried your first proposition. It works. Then take cam = PiCamera() out of the while loop. And finally, it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great!, i am glad my answer did help you :)